# Issue persisting with JPA from a Servlet

Tags: java, jpa, servlets, eclipselink

I try to persist an object with JPA and when I open the servlet, nothing happens in my database. It doesn't give me any exception, but nothing happens. Note that when I build my project I get the following warning:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
1 warning
```

My `persistence.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="QuizPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/quiz</jta-data-source>
    <class>Model.Categorie.Categorie</class>
    <class>Model.Exam.Exam</class>
    <class>Model.User.Etudiant</class>
    <class>Model.User.Prof</class>
    <class>Model.User.User</class>
    <class>SousCategorie.SousCategorie</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

glassfish-ressources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_quiz_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="quiz"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value=""/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_quiz_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

My `Servlet` code is:

```
package test;

import Model.Exam.Exam;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;



    public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("QuizPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Exam p = new Exam();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();
    em.persist(p);
     et.commit();
    em.close();
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Can anyone help me understand what the issue is?

Comment: which version of eclipseLink are you using

Comment: You are mix and matching config options.  transaction-type="JTA" should be resource-local if you are going to lookup and managed transactions from the em.  The jndi-name for the datasource you posted also doesn't seem right, so I don't know where JPA would be able to find the 'java:app/quiz' from.